# filtrado de fecha

Tags: php, sql, date

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito hacer un filtro de fecha de la columna saldos, por ejemplo que cuando seleccione la fecha maxima 2021-11-22 00:00:00 que muestre el resultado 183 pero con el siguiente codigo me muestra siempre el resultado 149, siempre selecciona el ultimo aun con el filtrado de fecha

BASE DE DATOS:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/38PrfMVrWrHXJUDGq3bdxm/12

```
SELECT m.codigo,m.nombre_material,uni.unidad,
(SELECT SUM(mo.cantidad) FROM movimientos AS mo WHERE mo.codigo_material = m.codigo and mo.tipo_movimiento='ENTRADA') AS entradas,
(SELECT SUM(mo.cantidad) FROM movimientos AS mo WHERE mo.codigo_material = m.codigo and mo.tipo_movimiento='SALIDA') AS salidas,
(SELECT mo.saldo FROM movimientos AS mo WHERE mo.codigo_material = m.codigo AND (identrada = (SELECT MAX(identrada) FROM movimientos)) ) AS saldo,
m.cantidad,mo.fecha from material as m 
inner join unidad_medida uni on  uni.idunidad_medida =  m.unidad 
inner join movimientos mo on mo.codigo_material= m.codigo 
where mo.fecha BETWEEN '2013-02-09 00:00:00' AND '2021-11-22 00:00:00'  
GROUP BY `m`.`codigo`  ASC  
ORDER BY `m`.`codigo`  DESC
```

Comment: lo que dices es imposible ... no tiene lógica ... ya que no es un comportamiento regular o un patrón que siempre se va a ejecutar ... pero para abarcar registro de días completos ... la ultima fecha debe terminar en `2021-11-22 23:59:59`

Comment: Mi problema es que simpre aparece el ultimo saldo que quedo, es decir el que tiene un mayor identrada.si coloco la fecha 2021-11-22 en teoria tendria que salir 183

Comment: no me queda claro y tu ejemplo no se reproduce ... puedes explicar detalladamente que hace tu query ... agregándolo al post?

Comment: según lo que has escrito agregar esto `AND mo.saldo=183` a tu clausula WHERE debería de resolverlo ...

Comment: Tengo un archivo php en donde solo hay dos input, en ellos pones una fecha de inicio y una fecha final, en la consulta qie coloque, puse esa fecha como ejemplo pero ahi va dependiendo de lo que ingresen, por ejemplo si coloco como fecha maxima 2021-11-22 23:59:59 tendria que ser el resultado 183 pero si yo colocara en los input la fecha 2021-12-02 23:59:59 tendria que aparecer 149

Comment: si pero el ejemplo que diste en  https://www.db-fiddle.com no se puede reproducir tiene errores

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K66b03ohEQh0UTYhePu_St-TSaLgqSRT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: lo lograste ver bro?

Comment: no suelo entrar a links de drive... solo uso lo que dejanen el post...

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/38PrfMVrWrHXJUDGq3bdxm/15

Comment: no se porque no da error con la db completa